# Qt creator Adding external library (still: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h')

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator, qt5

I followed the instruction:

1. In the Projects pane, open the project file (.pro).
2. Right-click in the code editor to open the context menu and select Add Library....

[image: Add Library]

Then the following lines were added into the pro file:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/D:/OpenGL/glew-1.5.4/lib/ -lglew32
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/D:/OpenGL/glew-1.5.4/lib/ -lglew32d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/D:/OpenGL/glew-1.5.4/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/D:/OpenGL/glew-1.5.4/include
```

However, I click the green triangle icon on the bottom left the run the program, still get the errors:

> error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem and I figured it out just now:
You have to run qmake(build->run qmake) to validate changes in the pro file.

Comment: qmake compiles your .pro file into a Makefile, which tells your compiler suite (e.g. gcc, clang, or msvc) how to compile the project.

Answer (score 1):

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:/OpenGL/glew-1.5.4/include
LIBS += -Lc:D:/OpenGL/glew-1.5.4/lib -lname
```

Just add the above line in the .pro file.Then check it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `.pro` file with Editor
2. Add directory of library in `INCLUDEPATH +=` section

[image]

```
 Append ` \` at the end of library path
```

3. Go to `Build > Run qmake`

[image]

4. Check if library has been included .

Comment: This assumes all developers use the same absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the desired files really exist under `D:/OpenGL/glew-1.5.4/include`. I.e. is there a folder named GL and inside it a file named glew.h?

Then try to remove the `$$PWD/` part from the paths.

If this doesn't help replace the generated lines with just those two lines:

```
LIBS += -L$$quote(D:/OpenGL/glew-1.5.4/lib/) -lglew32
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(D:/OpenGL/glew-1.5.4/include)
```