# INCLUDEPATH in qmake project file doesn't work

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I've got a problem with include in a qmake project. In my .pro file I've got:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\OpenCV\build\include"
```

and in my cpp :

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
```

The compiler indicates an error:

> Cannot open include file: 'opencv\cv.h': No such file or directory

but if I write this in my cpp:

```
#include "C:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv\cv.h"
```

it works!

I build the project from within Qt Creator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to set `INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\OpenCV\\build\\include"` and use `#include <opencv/cv.h>` in your source file?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work...

Comment: OK I found the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742856/qt-creator-adding-external-library-still-cannot-open-include-file-gl-glew-h I had the rerun qmake -.-'

Comment: @user2794529> Could you please accept an answer?

Comment: This question just saved my bacon: INCLUDEPATH += "C:\some\dir" in .pro, #include <subdir/header.h>, delete build- directory, qmake, and rebuild project.

Answer (score 17):

You have to run qmake(build->run qmake) to validate changes in the pro file.
[Qt creator Adding external library (still: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742856/qt-creator-adding-external-library-still-cannot-open-include-file-gl-glew-h/16747255#16747255)

Comment: Small tip: Qt cannot recognize spaces in path.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem may be related to the fact that having backslashes in naked `#include` directives [is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790161/is-the-backslash-acceptable-in-c-and-c-include-directives).

Do the following.

1. Replace your include with

   ```
   #include <opencv/cv.h>
   ```

   Note the forward slash!
2. Remove the shadow build directory that Qt Creator has made for you. You will find it above the project directory, its name begins with `build-`.
3. Rebuild the project.

Note that this takes care of rerunning qmake.

Comment: I can add that backslashes should be replaced to forward slashes in INCLUDEPATH content too.

Answer (score 3):

here's one of my pro files:

```
    # Blah Application

TEMPLATE  = app
CONFIG   += qt console staticlib debug_and_release
QT       -= gui
QT       += network sql xml
TARGET    = blah

CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
    DESTDIR = debug
    LIBS += -L../../../lib/core/debug -lcore
} else {
    DESTDIR = release
    LIBS += -L../../../lib/core/release -lcore
}
DEPENDPATH  += . ../../lib ../../../lib/core
INCLUDEPATH += . ../../lib ../../../lib/core

# Library files
HEADERS += mtBlahRTP.h
SOURCES += mtBlahRTP.cpp

# Input
HEADERS +=
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

The include path points to the RELATIVE directory of my lib files. mtBlahRTP.h and mtBlahRTP.cpp are in ../../lib

Answer (score 3):

I have the same question, before building or running, you should **qmake**(*Build=>qmake*) it.

My configurations for *INCLUDEPATH*:

```
INCLUDEPATH+=D:\opencv\opencv\build\include
INCLUDEPATH+=D:\opencv\opencv\build\include\opencv
INCLUDEPATH+=D:\opencv\opencv\build\include\opencv2
```

Comment: When using multiple line `INCLUDEPATH`'s, make sure you use `+=` (not `=`) - as I just found out to my cost

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and what I found is that the QtCreator IDE is not re-reading the results of qmake and updating the "Cannot open" message.  You need to close the offending file and re-open it - then you'll see that it no longer displays the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do two steps: (re-)run qmake and rebuild the whole project - only then the INCLUDEPATH setting was considered correctly. (With QtCreator 3.5 and 3.6 (Qt 5.5 and Qt 5.6) on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

The only problem you are making is incorrectly linking the OpenCV library. The other answers given here may or may not work, but I have posted on another thread a surefire way to solve this problem using the "Add Library" wizard inside Qt Creator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51914928/10245006

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error:

```
canserialcomm.o: In function `CanSerialComm::CanSerialComm()':
canserialcomm.cpp:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `vtable for CanSerialComm'
```

It turns out that the cause was it wasn't able to find `canserialcomm.h` where that constructor is declared. This was despite me having `INCLUDEPATH` in the project file point to the directory containing that header file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += . \
        ..
```

What I had to do to fix this is explicitely specify the header file; I added:

```
HEADER += ../canserialcomm.h
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use double backslashes when in windows for qt creator with msvc. like this: 
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libcurl\\libcurl-vc-x64-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl\\include

this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Under windows you have to eliminate the -I before each directory that is added into the INCLUDEPATH variable.
For example:
Under windows:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\lib\boost_1_61_0" (back-slash)
```

Under linux & mac:

```
INCLUDEPATH += -I"$$(HOME)/lib/boost_1_61_0" (note the -I and forward-slash)
```

I'm not sure whether it depends on different qmake version or not. But after finishing qmake command, I check the Makefile and the double -I is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do several things. Fist, in the .pro file, you need quotation marks two backslashes at a time, like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\OpenCV\\build\\include\\opencv\\cv.h"
```

You alse need a frontslash in the `#include` in your .cpp file like this:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
```

When you've done this, delete the build folder. This is the folder with a very complicated name of the type `build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Release`. Then, in the Build menu, press "Run qmake". When you've done all this, it should compile fine.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it did not work for when I had several INCLUDEPATH +=. 
When I combined the stuff into a single on it suddenly worked.