# INCLUDEPATH in QT doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, include

Sorry for the duplicate, but the solution from [INCLUDEPATH in qmake project file doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048098/includepath-in-qmake-project-file-doesnt-work) (running qmake) does not work for me.

While this works:

```
include "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/include/pcl-1.6/pcl/point_types.h" (in the .cpp)
```

following doesnt (no such file or directory), even after running qmake:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/include" (in the .pro file)
#include <pcl/point_types.h> (in the .cpp)
```

My .pro files looks like this:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = untitled
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/include"
```

I must be missing something really obvious but I have no idea what it is. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your paths are different. `../PCL 1.6.0/include/pcl-1.6/pcl/point_types.h` != `../PCL 1.6.0/include/pcl/point_types.h`.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow thought that it would also include the subfolders.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer so you can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your paths are different.

`../PCL 1.6.0/include/pcl-1.6/pcl/point_types.h` !=

`../PCL 1.6.0/include/pcl/point_types.h.`

Either use `INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/include/pcl-1.6"` in your .pro file
or include your header like this: `#include <pcl-1.6/pcl/point_types.h>`