# Headers not found when using Qt5 and Crypto++

Tags: c++, qt, crypto++

I have compiled and tried to link the cryptopp library to my .pro file but I get this error:

```
error: 'cryptopp/aes.h' file not found
#include <cryptopp/aes.h>
```

Below is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Journal
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a -lcryptopp
CONFIG += console c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    encrypt.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    filesio.h \
    encrypt.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

How could I resolve this error?
Thanks

Comment: You have to specify location of your include files. You can refer to `INCLUDEPATH` specifier: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath .

Comment: Change `LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a -lcryptopp` to `LIBS += -lcryptopp` or `LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib-lcryptopp -lcryptopp`

Comment: When the libraries are `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`  it is not necessary to indicate the path

Comment: I changed LIBS to both of those and still received them same error and then I tried the INCLUDEPATH specifier and still the same error appeared. The editor can find the files and can view the headers but only when compiling do I receive the error about not being able to find these headers

Comment: [How to add include path in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2752352/608639) and maybe [INCLUDEPATH in qmake project file doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19048098/608639) (but it looks like the first issue since there is no indication of including the Crypto++ library headers).

Comment: After running QMake with the include path specified it began to work thanks everyone for their assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by vahancho, you need to add below line in you qmake project file.

> INCLUDEPATH += path to parent directory of 'cryptopp'